# What's DING!? Shell prompt with time in it

Tags: shell, tcsh

I am using tcsh shell. I put time in my shell prompt. It shows me DING! sometimes, what's up with that?

```
/home/snihalani on master at 2:55pm 
=>

/home/snihalani on master at DING!
=>

/home/snihalani on master at 3:00pm
=>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently, it's a feature of tcsh. It's telling you the hour changed. Look in the man page for tcsh (e.g. [here](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tcsh) on the web, or on your system, of course) and you'll find reference to a variable `noding` that can turn it off.

Answer (score 1):

That's just the once-per-hour sound of your clock dinging. (It doesn't make any actual sound, because that would be annoying.) To catch your attention and make you realize how many hours you spend at the computer, or something like that.

I can remember when the man page use to have a credit specifically for the person who contributed the "DING!" code. It's gone now. And there's an option (`set noding`) to disable the "DING!" too.